# Find command, -exec tail and file browser

Tags: find, tail

I want to use the `find` command and open the file browser (Nemo) with the results:

This does it

```
find . -name "foo*" -exec nemo {} +
```

It opens a new window for each result. So to avoid opening tons of windows if the results are too many, I want to use the command `tail -<number>` to constraint the number of windows.

This does not work:

```
find . -name "foo*" -exec tail -1 {} \; -exec nemo {} +
```

Since opens all the windows.

Is there a way to get the second `-exec` take as parameter the first `-exec`? Or am I misunderstanding something?

> Use case: xfce menu > search commands, wich will take the string to find as parameter: `find /my/home/dir -name "*%s*" -exec tail -<x> {} \; -exec nemo {} +`. Note that if I (accidentally) search for the string "a" could have hundreds of results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
find . -name "foo*" -exec tail -1 {} \; -exec nemo {} +
```

you are executing `tail` on the contents of each file found, rather than on the list of filenames.

At lease with GNU Coreutils, you could do something like

```
find . -name "foo*" -print0 | tail -zn 1 | xargs -0 nemo
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this works in the shell but not in the whisker menu. It seems to be the xargs. I say this because the same thing happens for example with this command `ls -1 /path | grep "%s" | xargs nemo`. Works in the shell only.

Comment: @guillermochamorro that sounds more like a question about XFCE and/or the Whisker menu than about `find` or `tail`

Comment: Yes probably. I just assumed that it will execute any command irrespective of xfce. I will accept your answer since it solves the command. Thank you.